# jasmin-node not working in Windows

Tags: node.js, jasmine-node

I'm trying to run jasmine-node from Windows cmd with no success.
My package.json is at the top level of my project, with the following

```
{
    "devDependencies": {
    "jasmine-node": ""
    }
}
```

I run this at the top level of my project.

```
npm install
```

And then this

```
node_modules/jasmine-node/bin/jasmine-node spec/greetSpec.js
```

This is the result

```
'node_modules' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

What went wrong with installing jasmin-node?
What is the proper way to do this in Windows?

Answer (score 6):

It seems you were reading the same book as I am right now.

All you need to do is to put the `node` command before the path 
`node_modules/jasmine-node/bin/jasmine-node spec/greetSpec.js` and use backslashes `\` just like this:

```
node node_modules\jasmine-node\bin\jasmine-node spec\greetSpec.js
```